# TPL Dataflow. Cannot attach BatchBlock to ActionBlock. Type argument cannot be inferred from usage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, tpl-dataflow

I have this batch block as

```
var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<IEnumerable<string>>(10000,
                                                           new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions
                                                               {
                                                                CancellationToken = cancellationToken,
                                                                TaskScheduler = taskScheduler
                                                               }
                                                     );
```

And this ActionBlock as

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<string>>(enumerable =>
                                                       {

                                                           for (var i = 0;
                                                                i < enumerable.Count();
                                                                i++)
                                                           {
                                                               File.AppendAllText(@"D:\Test.log",
                                                                 enumerable.ElementAt(i));

                                                           }
                                                       });
```

When I try to attach them as

`batchBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock);`

I get an error saying `The type arguments for method System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.DataflowBlock.LinkTo<TOutput>(System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ISourceBlock<TOutput>, System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ITargetBlock<TOutput>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

and I get this very same error even when I do this..

`batchBlock.LinkTo((ActionBlock<IEnumerable<string>>)actionBlock);`

However, the compiler doesn't complains when instead of attaching a create a new `ActionBlock` in the constructor` such as

```
batchBlock.LinkTo(new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<string>[]>(enumerable => { /* log to file */ }));
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Why is it not letting me attach my `actionBlock` to `batchBlock`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type signature for the `LinkTo` extension method should shed some light on what's wrong:

```
LinkTo<TOutput>(ISourceBlock<TOutput>, ITargetBlock<TOutput>)
```

You're specifying a `BatchBlock<T>` as the source, and an `ActionBlock<T>` as the target, with the generic type `T` being `IEnumerable<string>`. However, the former implements `ISourceBlock<T[]>`, whilst the latter implements `ITargetBlock<T>`; thus, they are incompatible for being specified as arguments to the `LinkTo` method, which expects them to have the same type.

To fix this, you need to change your signature (and implementation) of `actionBlock` to:

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<string>[]>(enumerables => ...
                                                  // ^ accept an array of enumerables
```